# Washer: Whirlpool WFW95HEDW0, spin cycle isn't really spinning out the clothes (leaves them wet)

Tags: appliances, washing-machine

- Make: Whirlpool
- Model Name: Duet Direct Drive
- Model Number: WFW95HEDW0

**The problem**: Often, the spin cycle fails to get the laundry really dry. That, AND I notice that after the cycle runs, there is no visible water in the drum, but if I turn the drum by hand, I can hear water sloshing

**What I have done**:

- I checked the filter on the pump (on bottom, under drum) -- it was not clogged
- I checked the drain line from the back of the washer to the wall. It had water in it, but is not obstructed.
- I went into diagnostic mode, and ran ALL diagnostics. There were no error codes during diags
- When I first went into diag mode, there were some error codes: F08 and E03, 
  But I think those are old. I cleared them

My only other observation is that during diags, it took a LONG time to spin up to full speed (a minute or two), and at one point early on the whole washer shook a lot (which then passed)

(And after the diags, there was invisible water below the drum that sloshed when I turn the drum.)

**How to diagnose further?**

Answer (score 1):

I would check the pump again. If it's 120 Volts, remove the connections and jump it to a 120 Volt source and see if it drains the rest of the water out. The spin cycle will not function correctly with water remaining in the drum. Maybe remove pump from the drum and make sure nothing is clogged inside by the impeller. It seems that the pump just isn't doing its job.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that water down below the drum was normal, mine does it. Or I have a broken machine too and didn't realize it. I assume it was normal because there is no way all the water can get up and over the drain, there has to be water to push water, unless there's a check valve stopping it from flowing back down

The only time that I've had issues with wet clothes was because there was an in balance during the spin cycle, usually due to either a larger item like a blanket or one water retaining item with small items, like a heavy hoodie with underwear. Sometimes it doesn't shut it down, but just spins slower.

A slow spin up usually occurs when, well, I don't know. Mine is in the basement so I really don't know how fast it spins up. I would assume slow, because that puts less torque on everything, lowers power spikes, lowers motor size, lowers stress on parts therefore can be made less expensively.

I would try running another cycle with clothes that you know are not likely to cause an out of balance situation and are relatively light. No heavy towels, etc. Med to small items. If nothing else, as another troubleshooting step, to verify that it happens every time.

Comment: Yes, you'll have about two cups of water backflow into the drum but that little water doesn't slosh...

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would check or just change is your drive belt, they might look ok but they stretch over time and your machine won’t get up to speed during spin cycle, usually an under $20 fix and doesn’t hurt to change every couple years

Comment: This is a direct drive system... no belts...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/147767)